# Array Values not syncing - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the below code for pushing alerts. But the funny thing is when it passes thru the closeAlert(), the this.alerts and the local alerts in showAlert() does not sync up the values after _.difference is made.

```
public showAlert(containerName: string, alertType: string, message: string, dismissTimeout?: number): void {
    var alerts = this.alerts;

    var alert = <ICustomAlert>{
        dismissTimeout: dismissTimeout,
        message: message,
        type: alertType,
        container: containerName
    };

    if (_.findWhere(alerts, <ICustomAlert>{ message: message, type: alertType, container: containerName })) {
        this.closeAlert(containerName);
    }

    alerts.push(alert);
}

public closeAlert(containerName: string = "default", index?: number): void {
    var alerts = this.alerts;
    var withoutList = _.where(alerts, { container: containerName });

    if (angular.isDefined(index)) {
        withoutList = withoutList.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.alerts = _.difference(alerts, withoutList);   
}
```

My initial fix is to modify the alerts.push into:

```
this.alerts.push(alert);
```

I want to understand why the arrays are not syncing up when we just use alerts.push in showAlert(). Thanks.